# Max/min flow for scheduling slots

Tags: graph-theory, max-flow, ford-fulkerson, feasibility

So imagine there is a bus schedule:

These are return routes.

- NYE<->LND 2 buses needed
- NYE<->STN 3 buses needed
- STN<->LND 2 buses needed

Single arrow signifies one-way journey. Note NYE->LND is one way.

In the graph, NYEdep is NYE departure slot, LNDarr is LND arrival slot.

Now the thing is there are departure and arrival slots. Each slot can take one bus.

I am trying to map this in a min/max flow, to test feasibility. The numbers are the capacities. This example is clearly infeasible.[image]

But also it doesn't not make sense, one could start in NYE->LND, take the 2 slot say, but this has to end in a LNDarr slot, but you could end up in STNarr instead.

Is there anyway to make this problem tighter by adding nodes?